# MySQL: REGEX Replace StackOverflow-style Comments (BOLD text)

Tags: mysql, regex, regexp-replace, mysql-8.0

**MySQL Version**: 8.0

I have a field that has markup-style comments, where double-asterisks in front of and behind text signify that the text between should be bold. What is the proper way to replace all instances of subsequent double-quotes with a different string? If I have a field that looks like this:

```
The word **bold** should be **bold** in each instance
```

I need the output to look like this

```
The word <strong>bold</strong> should be <strong>bold</strong> in each instance
```

I have tried to use `REGEXP_REPLACE`, but my regex knowledge is lacking

```
SET @markup = 'The word **bold** should be **bold** in each instance';

SELECT
REGEXP_REPLACE( @markup, '\*{2}(.*?)\*{2}','<strong>\$1</strong>') AS Markup;
```

Which results in the error:

```
Error Code: 3688. Syntax error in regular expression on line 1, character 1.
```

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7hthXC2n8nYNZoBrRKqR9q/5

Comment: You need `REGEXP_REPLACE( @markup, '\\*{2}(.*?)\\*{2}','<strong>$1</strong>') AS Markup; `

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That works, thank you. Can you please post that as an answer and I will mark it as solved?